# CopyFile flagged as undeclared identifier

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Created a Copy Function and when trying to use 'CopyFile' in it, at point of compiling, Delphi flags it as undeclared identifier.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
function TdmData.CopyAFile(Sourcefile, DestFile: string): boolean;
var Src, Dest : PChar;
begin
  Src := StrAlloc(Length(SourceFile)+1);
  Dest := StrAlloc(Length(DestFile)+1);
try
  StrPCopy(Src,SourceFile);
  StrPCopy(Dest,DestFile);

  result := (CopyFile(Src,Dest,FALSE));
finally
  StrDispose(Src);
  StrDispose(Dest);
end;
end;
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CopyFile` is a Windows API function that is declared in the `Windows` unit. You need to add `Windows` to your uses clause. Or, if you are using fully qualified namespaces, add `Winapi.Windows`.

The code should also avoid performing heap allocations and string copies that are in fact not necessary. You can replace the code in the question with this:

```
uses
  Windows; // or Winapi.Windows

....

function TdmData.CopyAFile(const SourceFile, DestFile: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := CopyFile(PChar(SourceFile), PChar(DestFile), False);
end;
```